# SignalR JavaScript client universal trigger

Tags: javascript, signalr

I need to attach an event to every hub.client method. 
For example:

```
 Hub.client.doSomething = function (e) {
          aFunction(e);
        };

    Hub.client.doSomethingElse = function (e) {
          aFunction(e);
        };
```

Is there a way to attach `aFunction()` to all client methods on the client level, without placing the function in each client method?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want your function to be attached to your existing handlers, or to be automatically used *instead* of defining handlers at all? You said *without placing the function in each client method*, which made me think you wanted the second option, but maybe you meant the other one.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I would like any new or old functions to automatically inherit aFunction()

Comment: *Old or new* both mean "existing", that is clearer now. *Automatically* is a bit more difficult, I think you'll have to do some sort of call to something which would *enhance* your handlers, like the solution I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about such callback available directly on hub proxy, but you could use `received` callback on `connection` object. (see [list of connection lifetime events](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#connectionlifetime) and [received definition](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client#connectionreceived-handlerdata-))

Be aware that `received` callback is called every time data is received by connection, this means, that if you have multiple hubs, it will be invoked when any of hub send data to client. This means, that you will have to inspect data received in callback and decide, if you should process this data (if it belongs to given hub, if it is real message, or just signalr internal message).

Answer (score 1):

With some JavaScript code you can achieve what you need, regardless of what SignalR provides out of the box:

```
var extend = function (proxy, ex) {
    var keys = Object.keys(proxy.client),
        aop = function (p, k, f) {
            var prev = p[k];
            return function () {
                f();
                prev.apply(p, arguments);
            };
        };

    keys.forEach(function (k) {
        proxy.client[k] = aop(proxy.client, k, ex);
    });
};

extend(Hub, aFunction);
```

It is enough to call the `extend` function on all your hub proxies after having defined your *real* handlers.

With some more effort this code can be made more solid and generic, but I think it should already put you in the right direction.

Comment: hmm, I probably understood question in a bit different way. I assumed, OP doesn't want to define catch-all function on hub, so he wouldn't have to define anything on else. But this is nice idea, I'll probably use this in one of projects :)

Comment: This solution does indeed work only on defined handlers. SignalR actually takes shortcuts if no handlers are defined at all, so it would be tricky to make it work otherwise, and in case it does it has to be the way you described, i.e.  by messing with its low level protocol (which might change in future versions, I'm not sure it's *public*).

Comment: As far as I know, it is public, since it is also available in C# client api. Problem is, that it doesn't seem to be used too much. Due to this, documentation is quite limited.

Comment: Agree, documentation is mostly reverse engineering done by some guys ([this one](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/) looks accurate). It's probably true that the protocol will mostly stay the same, or at least backward compatible, therefore any logic written over most stable parts of it will work quite happily in future.